# How to get name of the connections in OAuth2?

Tags: xero-api

After successfully establishing OAuth2 connection to Xero, call to https://api.xero.com/connections is giving only the id, tenant id and type.

How to get the name (display name) of the connections?

Tried calling Organizations API. It does not work in OAuth2

```
var url = "https://api.xero.com/connections";

  //var response = service.fetch(url, {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken(),
    },
    muteHttpExceptions : true
  });
```

There is no way of getting connection names and showing it to end-user to choose. (It makes no sense to ask the user to choose from the list of cryptic ids).

Answer (score 3):

You should retrieve each organisation from the /organisation endpoint, with the appropriate tenantId as the value in the xero-tenant-id header:

```
https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/organisation
```

This works with both OAuth1.0a and OAuth2 (note the 's' rather than the 'z' in the endpoint).

Comment: Also, be sure to ask for the 'accounting.settings.read' scope to be able to access the GET /Organisation endpoint

Comment: Thanks @rustyskates for this information. Call to /organisation works for single tenant id. So if there are 20 connections returned from https://api.xero.com/connections, just to get the name of the org, do we need to make 20 API calls?